# Java regex to pull data from string containing start and end tag

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know the regex to pull data from a string in Java which will have following start and end tag info.

```
 String temp = "<!--abc Start-->..data...<!--abc end-->"
```

So  bascially, I want to pull everything between

```
<!--abc Start-->
<!--abc end-->
```

and these can be in the string n number of time.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("");
Macher m = p.matcher(temp);
```

while(m.find())
....

so basically I am stuck at the regex

Comment: You mean to say that the only regex you tried was `""`?

Comment: +1 (offsetting) Willing to give young Nomad the benefit of the doubt, methinks Nomad is strong with the Java but not so much with the Regex.

Comment: it is hard to tell what format that is, but it looks suspiciously like XML and if it is, you [can't parse a non-Regular language like XML with an XML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=parse%20xml%20regex) ...

Comment: `"so basically I am stuck at the regex"`: the place to start is a good regex tutorial, and you can find many via Google.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to parse XML with regexes, which is a REALLY BAD IDEA™.  Please read the first answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Bob - not so strong with the searching either ... aren't there already 7-zillion questions on SO asking for a regex to extract data between tags?

Comment: @Stephen - You're absolutely right. My first instinct, as should @Nomad's, would be to hit the search engines, especially when you consider that 99.999% of the problems I've encountered have been encountered, and well documented, by better software engineers who have preceded me. Still, I have a soft spot for newbies here, especially since my first question was downvoted and closed for reasons that mystified me at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<!--abc Start-->(.*?)<!--abc end-->", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(temp);

while(m.find()) {
  String betweenStartAndEnd = m.group(1);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks all, for you input, really appreciate your time and help. I basically do get an xslt as a string which will have these <!--abc Start-->..<!--abc end-->, so I want to pull everything between these as this can be in the string n number of time.s

Comment: @Nomad, I think you were on the right path with the `while(m.find())`.  The loop above should execute the loop body once for each begin/end pair in the string.

Comment: Thanks a Mike for your answer and sorry for the delay reply and acceptance. I really appreciated your help, rather than other folks who were sarcastic and didn't answer the question.
Thanks again.